# How can I plot three dataset clustering

Tags: matlab, plot

I've been working on matlab and I've managed to plot kmean cluster with two dataset now I want to do the same but with three data set. Do I need to create 3d plot for three dataset or is it ok to just plot it normally 
 this is what I've been working on for the three data set

```
    Array=csvread('test.csv');
      dataset = Array(:,[1:3]);
      col1 = Array(:, 1);
      col2 = Array(:, 2);
      col3 = Array(:, 3);
    %dataset [mean+std.deviation *column];
      data1 = [3721.17+3872.307*col1];
      data2 = [3218.28+4754.122*col2];
      data3 = [1541.93+3783.942*col3];
      mydata = [data1, data2 ,data3];



  [idx,C] = kmeans(data,3,'Distance','cityblock',...
       'Options',optns);
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to plot three data set kmean cluster can I only use 'plot' or will it be better if I represent it in 3d plot
and how can I create 3d plot for three data set

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to approximate your situation. Note that the call to means uses `mydata`, not `data` as used in your code, because there is no variable called `data`.

```
Array=rand(100,3);
dataset = Array(:,[1:3]);
col1 = Array(:, 1);
col2 = Array(:, 2);
col3 = Array(:, 3);
%dataset [mean+std.deviation *column];
data1 = [3721.17+3872.307*col1];
data2 = [3218.28+4754.122*col2];
data3 = [1541.93+3783.942*col3];
mydata = [data1, data2 ,data3];

[idx,C] = kmeans(mydata,3,'Distance','cityblock');
```

Then to plot in 3d, and color code by the k-means separation, use the `scatter3` function.

```
scatter3(data1,data2,data3,[],idx,'filled');
```

or

```
scatter3(mydata(:,1),mydata(:,2),mydata(:,3),[],idx,'filled');
```

The use of idx in the 5th input argument will color code the scatter-point according to how they were grouped from the output of kmeans.